# Scraping images and text together with different parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, loops, web-scraping

I am doing some webscraping, and trying to get both the image, and text which is located in a different class, and then display them together. Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image>
    <img src="https://www.image.com/01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
   Apple
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image>
    <img src="https://www.image.com/02.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
   Banana
  </div>
</div>
```

So in my loop, I want to get both the image and the text.

```
const group: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    this.$('.thumbnail .image img[src]')
      .get()
      .forEach(img => {
        const $img = this.$(img);
        // Null Check
        const imgText = $img
          .siblings('.text')
          .text()
          .trim();
        group[imgText] = location.origin + imgText;
      });
    Type = { 'Fruit': group };
```

When I console log, I seem to be getting the image but not the text. I have tried siblings, next, closest etc. but none seem to work. I am also not sure what else I could put instead of location.origin.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can select all the images and with each image you can get the src and the closest `.thumbnail` from which you can get the text.

```
$(".thumbnail img").each(function(id, img) {
    var src = $(img).attr('src');
    var text = $(img).closest(".thumbnail").find('.text').text().trim();
})
```